# Merging Codeigniter with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

I'm trying to utilize the power of wordpress to set up a blog on my site.

I got it to install fine, but when trying to use wordpress's functions in a CI view the functions are undefined.

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/48347/ I am following this.

I put the require('blog/wp-blog-header.php') in my index.php file(ci) on the root.

Any idea where I am messing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why both integrating WordPress and CodeIgniter when you could just use PyroCMS and have your entire site running a single CI codebase?

http://pyrocms.com/

Comment: Isn't this cms like all others where you have to start building using the cms, rather than merging it to a existing site?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Phil, why integrate two completely different systems (a blog and a framework) when you can use existing solutions that can prevent a lot from going wrong?

Comment: To utilize all of the plugin's that wp has to offer was the main driving force behind it.